# nunit - set Order attribute from custom attribute of Test method

Tags: c#, nunit

Let's say we have a custom attribute:

```
[Precondition(1, "Some precondition")]
```

This would implement `[Test, Order(1), Description("Some precondition")]`

Can I access and modify the `Order` attribute (or create one) for this method?
I can modify the `Description` and `Author`, but Order is not a possibility.

I have tried

1: `context.Test.Properties["Order"][0] = order;`

2:`method.CustomAttributes.GetEnumerator()`

by walking the stack frames with

```
 Object[] attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PreconditionAttribute), false);
if (attributes.Length >= 1){...}
```

3:

```
OrderAttribute orderAttribute = (OrderAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(i, typeof(OrderAttribute));
orderAttribute.Order = _order;
```

Which is readonly.

If I try `orderAttribute.Order = new OrderAttribute(myOrd)`, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have two answers to choose from. One is in the vein of "Don't do this" and the other is about how to do it. Just for fun, I'm putting both answers up, separately, so they can compete with one another. This one is about why I don't think this is a good idea.

1. It's easy enough to write either

   `[Test, Order(1), Description("xxx")]` or the equivalent...

   `[Test(Description="xxx"), Order(1)]`
2. The proposed attribute gives users a second way to specify order, making it possible to assign two different orders to a test. Which of two attributes will win the day depends on (1) how each one is implemented, (2) the order in which the attributes are listed and (3) the platform on which you are running. For all practical purposes, it's non-deterministic.
3. Keeping the two things separate allows devs to decide which they need independently... which is why NUnit keeps them separate.
4. Using the standard attributes means that the devs can rely on the nunit documentation to tell them what the attributes do. If you implement your own attribute, you should document what it does in itself as well as what it does in the presence of the standard attributes... As stated above, that's difficult to predict.

I know this isn't a real answer in SO terms, but it's not pure opinion either. There are real technical issues in providing the kind of solution you want. I'd love to see what people think of it in comparison with "how to" I'm going to post next.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It’s not about being helpful, it’s about having different attribute names (although they would act just like a Test attr) and because I was curious. Thanks for the wise words though.

Answer (score 1):

See my prior answer first! If you **really** want to do this, here's the how-to...

In order to combine the action of two existing attributes, you need equivalent code to those two attributes.

In this case both are extremely simple and both have about the same amount of code. `DescriptionAttribute` is based on `PropertyAttribute` so some of its code is hidden. `OrderAttribute` has a bit more logic because it checks to make sure the order has not already been set. Ultimately, both of them have code that implements the `IApplyToTest` interface.

Because they are both simple, I would copy the code, in order to avoid relying on implementation details that could change. Start with the slightly more complete `OrderAttribute`. Change its name. Modify the ApplyToTest method to set the description. You're done!

It will look something like this, depending on the names you use for properties...

```
    public void ApplyToTest(Test test)
    {
        if (!test.Properties.ContainsKey(PropertyNames.Order))
            test.Properties.Set(PropertyNames.Order, Order);

        test.Properties.Set(PropertyNames.Description, Description);
    }
```

A comment on what you tried...

There is no reason to think that creating an attribute in your code will do anything. NUnit has no way to know about those attributes. Your attribute cannot modify the code so that the test magically has other attributes. The only way Attributes communicate with NUnit is by having their interfaces (like `IApplyToTest`) called. And only attributes actually present in the code will receive such a call.